# Breeze API Error Unable to locate member: When filtering on expanded entity

Tags: knockout.js, odata, breeze, single-page-application

I am getting the error:

```
Unable to locate member:
```

when filtering on an expanded entities property.

This works:

```
http://localhost:60760/XXX/XXX/productcollection?$filter=Code%20eq%20'da'&$expand=PRODUCT_LINE
```

And Returns:

```
[{"$id":"1","$type":"DoorDesigner.Models.COLLECTION, DoorDesigner","ID":81,"Descr":"Some Description","Code":"Da","DISPLAY_HTML":"","DEFAULT_IMAGE_PATH":"../Content/Images/TempCollections/0000_Layer 54.jpg","PRODUCT_LINE":[{"$id":"2","$type":"DoorDesigner.Models.PRODUCT_LINE, DoorDesigner","ID":213,"CollectionID":81,"Code":"AT","Descr":"ATHENA","LongDescr":"ATHENA","DEFAULT_IMAGE_PATH":"../Content/Images/TempCollections/0000_Layer%2054.jpg","Product_Code_Group":"AT","COLLECTION":{"$ref":"1"},"PRICING_DOOR":[],"POSSIBLE_INSULATION":[],"POSSIBLE_WINDOW":[],"WINDOWs":[]},{"$id":"3","$type":"DoorDesigner.Models.PRODUCT_LINE, DoorDesigner","ID":217,"CollectionID":81,"Code":"CY","Descr":"CYPRUS","LongDescr":"CYPRUS","DEFAULT_IMAGE_PATH":"../Content/Images/TempCollections/Panel.jpg","Product_Code_Group":"CY","COLLECTION":{"$ref":"1"},"PRICING_DOOR":[],"POSSIBLE_INSULATION":[],"POSSIBLE_WINDOW":[],"WINDOWs":[]},{"$id":"4","$type":"DoorDesigner.Models.PRODUCT_LINE, DoorDesigner","ID":220,"CollectionID":81,"Code":"PI","Descr":"PINNACLE","LongDescr":"PINNACLE","DEFAULT_IMAGE_PATH":"../Content/Images/TempCollections/Windows.jpg","Product_Code_Group":"PI","COLLECTION":{"$ref":"1"},"PRICING_DOOR":[],"POSSIBLE_INSULATION":[],"POSSIBLE_WINDOW":[],"WINDOWs":[]},{"$id":"5","$type":"DoorDesigner.Models.PRODUCT_LINE, DoorDesigner","ID":227,"CollectionID":81,"Code":"WI","Descr":"WINDRIVER","LongDescr":"WINDRIVER","DEFAULT_IMAGE_PATH":"../Content/Images/TempCollections/Panel.jpg","Product_Code_Group":"WI","COLLECTION":{"$ref":"1"},"PRICING_DOOR":[],"POSSIBLE_INSULATION":[],"POSSIBLE_WINDOW":[],"WINDOWs":[]}]}]
```

Notice, that `PRODUCT_LINE` is Expanded, and there is a `Descr` property.

Now, if I change the URL to filter on `PRODUCT_LINE.Descr` I get the error:

```
http://localhost:60760/XXX/XXX/productcollection?$filter=PRODUCT_LINE/Descr%20eq%20'Athena'&$expand=PRODUCT_LINE
```

Returning:

```
{"$id":"1","$type":"System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unable to locate member: Descr","ExceptionType":"System.Exception","StackTrace":"   at Breeze.WebApi.ParseTreeVisitor.VisitMemberExpr(ParseTreeNode node, Expression targetExpr, String memberName)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.ParseTreeVisitor.<>c__DisplayClass3.<VisitNode>b__0(ParseTreeNode n)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.ParseTreeVisitor.VisitNode(ParseTreeNode node)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.ParseTreeVisitor.VisitNode(ParseTreeNode node)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.ParseTreeVisitor.Parse(Type rootType, ParseTreeNode node)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.ExpressionTreeBuilder.Parse(Type rootType, String source)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.ODataActionFilter.BuildFilterFunc(String filterQueryString, Type elementType)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.ODataActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecuted(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpResponseMessage response, Exception exception)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync>b__0(HttpResponseMessage response)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass41`2.<Then>b__40(Task`1 t)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)"}
```

As far as I can tell, this is the Breeze code that is generating the error.

```
protected virtual Expression VisitMemberExpr(ParseTreeNode node, Expression targetExpr, String memberName) {
  var targetType = targetExpr.Type;
  var member = targetType.GetMember(memberName).FirstOrDefault();
  if (member == null) {
    throw new Exception("Unable to locate member: " + memberName);
  }
  return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(targetExpr, member);
}
```

This is happening throughout my API, anywhere that I try to filter on an Expanded Property. Has anyone been successful at filtering on these?

UPDATE:
Here is the Entity Query:

`breeze.EntityQuery.from('ProductCollection')
      .where('PRODUCT_LINE.Descr', '==', 'Athena')
      .expand('PRODUCT_LINE');`

AND in the APIController

`[HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<COLLECTION> productCollection() {
      return _contextProvider.Context.COLLECTIONs;
    }`

The Context Definition:

`public DbSet<COLLECTION> COLLECTIONs { get; set; }`

And Finally the Class definitions

```
public partial class COLLECTION
{
    public COLLECTION()
    {
        this.PRODUCT_LINE = new HashSet<PRODUCT_LINE>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Descr { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string DISPLAY_HTML { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CREATED { get; set; }
    public string CREATOR { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LAST_MODIFIED { get; set; }
    public string LAST_USER { get; set; }
    public string DEFAULT_IMAGE_PATH { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IS_DELETED { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PRODUCT_LINE> PRODUCT_LINE { get; set; }
}

public partial class PRODUCT_LINE
{
    public PRODUCT_LINE()
    {
        this.PRICING_DOOR = new HashSet<PRICING_DOOR>();
        this.POSSIBLE_INSULATION = new HashSet<POSSIBLE_INSULATION>();
        this.POSSIBLE_WINDOW = new HashSet<POSSIBLE_WINDOW>();
        this.WINDOWs = new HashSet<WINDOW>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CollectionID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Descr { get; set; }
    public string LongDescr { get; set; }
    public string DISPLAY_HTML { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CREATED { get; set; }
    public string CREATOR { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LAST_MODIFIED { get; set; }
    public string LAST_USER { get; set; }
    public string DEFAULT_IMAGE_PATH { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IS_DELETED { get; set; }
    public string Product_Code_Group { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DefaultInsulationId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DefaultWindowId { get; set; }

    public virtual COLLECTION COLLECTION { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PRICING_DOOR> PRICING_DOOR { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<POSSIBLE_INSULATION> POSSIBLE_INSULATION { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<POSSIBLE_WINDOW> POSSIBLE_WINDOW { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WINDOW> WINDOWs { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please post a copy of your entity query.  I believe the problem has to do with the fact you are trying to filter on a property in an expanded entity that has not yet been expanded, but if you can post your entity query I can help confirm (or deny : )) that

Comment: `breeze.EntityQuery.from('ProductCollection')
      .orderBy('Descr')
      .where('PRODUCT_LINE.Descr', '==', 'Athena')
      .expand('PRODUCT_LINE');`

Comment: So ProductCollection has PRODUCT_LINE's which have a Descr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this error. Somehow I had a reference to Breeze 1.1.2, which did not show that it had any updates in the Package Manager. I finally realized that if i searched for breeze, it found v 1.3.6 to be the current version (which is what i assumed the project was on anyway).

An update to the current version of breeze resolved the issue.

kadumel => thanks for your valuable input!

Answer (score 1):

One thing about this that doesn't make sense to me - is your ProductCollection a collection of Product's or an entity of type ProductCollection?

*Edit*

In your ApiController you are naming ProductCollection as productCollection, is that on purpose or a typo? Also, your collection of PRODUCT_LINE's is called PRODUCT_LINE, which one would think you meant to name it PRODUCT_LINES. Last, your ForeignKey is nullable (CollectionId), are you sure it is not null?

Comment: It does in fact have a field named Descr I know the name is confusing, it is a Collection of Products (PRODUCT_LINES). I added the definitions to the original post. Also this still errors: `   query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('ProductCollection')
        .where('PRODUCT_LINE.Descr', '==', 'Athena')
        .expand('PRODUCT_LINE');`

Comment: And you are not using camelCase as the default or anything correct?

Comment: No, Interesting though. I had an error early on with camelCase 
 
     function configureBreezeManager() {
        // This was causing breeze to error stating that the server "Key" and client "key" names do not match (key is derived from metadata...) 
        //        breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
        var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager(config.remoteServiceName);
        model.configureMetadataStore(mgr.metadataStore);
        return mgr;
      }

Comment: Alright last question, in your ApiController you are naming ProductCollection as productCollection, is that on purpose or a typo?  Also, your collection of PRODUCT_LINE's is called PRODUCT_LINE, which one would think you meant to name it PRODUCT_LINES.  Last, your ForeignKey is nullable (CollectionId), are you sure it is not null?

Comment: It was a Typo, related to my camelCasing getting commented out. I fixed the casing error, and still the same issue. We are using EF, and it is not pluralizing PRODUCT_LINE. Got tired of changing on every model update... Do you think this could be the issue? Also, Looking in the Data, the ForiegnKey is not null.

Comment: Not sure best bet is to wait for jay to give an answer your model is fairly complicated and he is the man to know what else to look at

Comment: Thanks for the effort, much appreciated!